# Adding the values generated by multiple terminal commands in the terminal itself

Tags: networking, ubuntu-14.04, wireshark, pcap, tcpdump

Can we add the values generated by multiple commands? For example, I am analysing this pcap file using tcpdump, and by doing this - capinfos -s *.pcap, I am getting all the pcap files' size, line by line. Can anyone tell me how to add those in the terminal itself? I'm not expecting appending the values in csv or txt file and add those.

Comment: When I do `capinfos -s *.pcap`, I'm not _getting all the pcap files' size, line by line_, but rather a combination of lines with `File name:`, `File size:`, possibly `Packet size limit:` and empty lines.

Comment: capinfos -s *.pcap >> filename.txt  and then sed -i.bak 's/[^[:digit:]]\+//g' filename.txt   Add this after that, it will extract the numbers only from the file.

Comment: Are you aware that this `sed` command also extracts other numbers, for example if part of the file name? Would you accept a modified way of getting the sizes?

Comment: Yeah, i just got to know that, but I found the alternative awk command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `awk` both for filtering the size lines and for adding the sizes (`$3`, as `$1` is `File` and `$2` is `size:`):

```
capinfos -s *.pcap|awk '/File size:/ {sum += $3}
                        END          {print sum}'
```